# Android error on multicore processors

Tags: java, android, multithreading, multicore

I am developing a multi threaded application, that uses both threads and Async tasks to execute code on multiple threads.

I have an AsyncTask that adds a row to a database, and then sends off an API request. Once the API request reply is received, it updates the row in the database. The database adapter object is passed to the AsyncTask from the UI thread.

Unfortunately, the AsyncTask doesn't work on multi core devices (such as the Asus Transformer). A null pointer exception occurs when I try to add the row to the database for the first time.

I don't know why this happens, but it may be something to do with what is says in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) under 'Memory Observability'.

Comment: Please post some code where the error appears, otherwise there is no way for us to know what is happening.

Comment: Unless you're doing something strange, there shouldn't be a difference on multi-core devices. You're just dealing with threads, while the vm deals with the cores. More likely your test phone is just fast, and you're hitting a race condition you don't meet on slower phones.

Comment: If it helps narrowing down the issue, I have a multicore phone and use AsyncTask to run multiple concurrent threads in my app but have no issues.

Comment: Okay then, assuming it is a race condition, a) how should I go about finding how this is occurring b) how could a race condition cause a NullPointerException? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: That's difficult to say without the code, but hitting a NPE is probably due to using a field which should contain an object instance that hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments guys.

It turns out I did have a race condition. I didn't realise that onActivityResult was called before onResume, and so it turned out that on slower phones, the runnable task would be executed after onResume was called (and so the database had been opened), but on faster phones, the runnable task would get to the database operation first and be met with a NPE.

Thanks!